# How To Print Only Selected Arrays (Based on Search)

Tags: php

I have the code below that basically reads Spotify Charts table and prints it.

What I want to do now is only print rows from a specific artist, **e.g**. Post Malone. So '`Post Malone`' would have to be on the row array. I tried it several ways, but nothing works. Can anyone give me a light in which direction to go?

```
<?php
include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://spotifycharts.com/regional/us/daily/latest');
$table = $html->find('table', 0);

$rowData = array();

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    $onerow = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
            $onerow[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }
    $rowData[] = $onerow;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($tr as $td)
        echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: The tricky part is that it has the song name in it too. So this is an array for the first row: `('1', 'rockstar by Post Malone', '1,217,306')`

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
 if(strpos($cell->(your name column),"Post Malone") !== false){
        $onerow[] = $cell->plaintext; 
 }
}
```

try like this

Comment: Since `strpos` may return int(0), it's important to go with `if (strpos() !== false)`

Comment: you should strpos whole table row, not only table cell